# Installing Erlang & RabbitMQ on debian - package issues

Tags: debian, aptitude, packages, erlang

I'm trying to get RabbitMQ setup, but something funky is going on with my dependencies. I'm running a Debian 7.1 that will be used as a server, hence has no desktop environment. I try to install rabbitmq-server using aptitude:

```
$ apt-get install rabbitmq-server 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Package rabbitmq-server is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
E: Package 'rabbitmq-server' has no installation candidate
```

Getting the .deb file from the RabbitMQ site yields the following dependency error:

```
$ dpkg -i rabbitmq-server_3.1.3-1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package rabbitmq-server.
(Reading database ... 31422 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking rabbitmq-server (from rabbitmq-server_3.1.3-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prvent configuration of rabbitmq-server:
 rabbitmq-server depends on erlang-nox (>= 1:12.b.3) | esl-erlang; however:
  Package erlang-nox is not installed.
  Package esl-erlang is not installed.
```

Trying to install erlang-nox by itself yields similar results:

```
$ apt-get install erlang-nox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Package erlang-nox is not available, but is referred to by another package. 
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
E: Package 'erlang-nox' has no installation candidate
```

My sources list is the following:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
...
deb http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates main contrib
#deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian testing main
```

The last line was added after I failed to install rabbiqmq-server through the above procedures, but did not work either.

I tried installing erlang manually (compiling and using make install), but rabbitmq still complained about it and would not install.

Any pointers as to what could possibly be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sources.list` is missing the main Debian repository. Add this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and try installing `rabbitmq-server` again:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

As you can see [here](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/rabbitmq-server), the `rabbitmq-server` is indeed in the main debian repository, so after adding the line above you should be able to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

Just make sure to choose a [debian mirror](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list) that is close to you and edit the deb line accordingly.

Comment: That worked. I should've picked up on that, but how is the main depository not included after a clean OS Install? Perhaps it was excluded when I unchecked the Desktop environment, but still pretty weird. Thank you, and sorry for getting back to you so late.

Comment: @user991710 no idea, it is strange, maybe a change you made at some point?